# HTML5: Device Pixel Ratio VS Software Zoom

Tags: html, retina, hdpi, zooming

How can I reliably distinguish between the device's pixel ratio and the browser's zoom setting? My website needs to adapt to each of these in a different manner, so the product of these two data points is inadequate: window.devicePixelRatio.